# s3 bucket を rubygems の置き場として取り扱うような方法・ライブラリはある?

Tags: ruby, aws, rubygems, amazon-s3

docker には、 docker repository のバックエンドを s3 bucket にすることができます。 https://docs.docker.com/registry/storage-drivers/s3

ふと、同様のことが rubygems でも実現可能なのではないか、と思いました。

#### 質問

- rubygems.org のような、 gem ファイルをホストするサーバーのバックエンドを s3 にする方法、ライブラリなどはありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

[Gem in a Box](https://github.com/geminabox/geminabox)というプロジェクトでローカルサーバーを立てることが出来るそうです。
https://github.com/geminabox/geminabox

そのプロジェクト内でS3をサポートしようというissueは立てられていますがまだサポートはされていないようです。
https://github.com/geminabox/geminabox/issues/264

こちらにGem in a BoxのstorageをS3にするプロジェクトも立てられていて、[issue内](https://github.com/geminabox/geminabox/issues/77)でも言及されているので、公式サポートされるのも有り得るかと思います。
https://github.com/bkon/geminabox-s3-store